# What does "res.render" do, and what does the html file look like?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

> What does `res.render` do, and what does the html file look like?

My end goal is to load arbitrary comma-separated-values from a text file into an html file (for example). I was only able to deduce that a view was the html file, and callback gives that html file back.

Here is the documentation: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render.

Now, given context from some example code I found, there is something about using `ejs` (embedded javascript) with `<%` and `%>`.

But if I may add, am I just incompetent or is the documentation really truly vague and assumes the reader knows everything? How could I have gone about figuring this out on my own? Is there any official documentation so I can gain a full understanding of usage, advantages and pitfalls?

---

**Edit 1**

I just want to add that I'm having a heck of a time learning `node.js`. 
Is it me or is the general documentation really vague? Aside from lousy explanations like above, there are no type specifications for parameters or return values.

---

**Edit 2**

Let me ask you some more specific questions above the code.

The actual `orders.ejs` file is in `views/orders.ejs`. How does this code refer to it?

HTML excerpt:

```
<tbody>
  <% for(var i=0; i<orders.length; i++) {%>
     <tr>
       <td><%= orders[i].id %></td>
       <td><%= orders[i].amount %></td>
       <td><%= orders[i].time %></td>
     </tr>
     <% } %>
```

And the js. Please see /orders:

```
  // Define routes for simple SSJS web app. 
// Writes Coinbase orders to database.
var async   = require('async')
  , express = require('express')
  , fs      = require('fs')
  , http    = require('http')
  , https   = require('https')
  , db      = require('./models');

var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

// Render homepage (note trailing slash): example.com/
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  var data = fs.readFileSync('index.html').toString();
  response.send(data);
});

// Render example.com/orders
app.get('/orders', function(request, response) {
  global.db.Order.findAll().success(function(orders) {
    var orders_json = [];
    orders.forEach(function(order) {
      orders_json.push({id: order.coinbase_id, amount: order.amount, time: order.time});
    });
    // Uses views/orders.ejs
    response.render("orders", {orders: orders_json});
  }).error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    response.send("error retrieving orders");
  });
});

// Hit this URL while on example.com/orders to refresh
app.get('/refresh_orders', function(request, response) {
  https.get("https://coinbase.com/api/v1/orders?api_key=" + process.env.COINBASE_API_KEY, function(res) {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {body += chunk;});
    res.on('end', function() {
      try {
        var orders_json = JSON.parse(body);
        if (orders_json.error) {
          response.send(orders_json.error);
          return;
        }
        // add each order asynchronously
        async.forEach(orders_json.orders, addOrder, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            response.send("error adding orders");
          } else {
            // orders added successfully
            response.redirect("/orders");
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.send("error parsing json");
      }
    });

    res.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      response.send("error syncing orders");
    });
  });

});

// sync the database and start the server
db.sequelize.sync().complete(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
      console.log("Listening on " + app.get('port'));
    });
  }
});

// add order to the database if it doesn't already exist
var addOrder = function(order_obj, callback) {
  var order = order_obj.order; // order json from coinbase
  if (order.status != "completed") {
    // only add completed orders
    callback();
  } else {
    var Order = global.db.Order;
    // find if order has already been added to our database
    Order.find({where: {coinbase_id: order.id}}).success(function(order_instance) {
      if (order_instance) {
        // order already exists, do nothing
        callback();
      } else {
        // build instance and save
          var new_order_instance = Order.build({
          coinbase_id: order.id,
          amount: order.total_btc.cents / 100000000, // convert satoshis to BTC
          time: order.created_at
        });
          new_order_instance.save().success(function() {
          callback();
        }).error(function(err) {
          callback(err);
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: You are not wrong about the docs being vague. When you get more experience, maybe you could update them. I would but I probably don't have any more experience than you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> What does res.render do and what does the html file look like?

`res.render()` function *compiles your template* (please don't use ejs), inserts locals there, and creates html output out of those two things.

---

Answering **Edit 2** part.

```
// here you set that all templates are located in `/views` directory
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// here you set that you're using `ejs` template engine, and the
// default extension is `ejs`
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// here you render `orders` template
response.render("orders", {orders: orders_json});
```

So, the template path is `views/` (first part) + `orders` (second part) + `.ejs` (third part) === `views/orders.ejs`

---

Anyway, express.js documentation is good for what it does. It is API reference, not a "how to use node.js" book.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Why not use ejs? What do I use then? I understand it can't go down to teaching my syntax but I think render() is a method provided by express and it fails to explain its own function. I posted code above. I am really confused about how it accesses views/order.ejs because the first argument to render is just "orders." I thought the views subdirectory and .ejs file type was automatic but now I hear that it is optional from you?

Comment: Answering first part of the question, `ejs` doesn't separate executable code from the template. Sometimes it's good as a general-purpose templating language, but `jade` or `handlebars` are usually better for generating html.

Comment: But who says that render() uses the 'views' and 'view engine' setting. Where is that in documentation?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/api.html says: `views - The view directory path, defaulting to "process.cwd() + '/views'"`

Comment: From the same docs: `view engine - The default engine extension to use when omitted`

Comment: Forget it, trivial question, will figure it out later via testing. Thank you very much! If you see this, one last question: is there a description for render() function? For example, without the sample code above, I would never have known that 'locals' is a dictionary that gets processed and then the html file gets rendered.

Comment: Yeah, you can use them in your template as usual. If you're using ejs, just write regular `<script>...</script>` there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry, that was a silly question because I could've easily experimented. I edited my comment above though with the root problem I am having with all this. I'm struggling finding resources to learn.
I really appreciate you finding the views and view engine in the settings. If you would also find the docs for render() for me because I looked an hour and only found sample code. My fear is that I'm missing a whole database of information and that I will keep having this problem where I don't know what functions do.

Answer (score 6):

Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client.

```
res.render('index');
```

Or

```
res.render('index', function(err, html) {
  if(err) {...}
  res.send(html);
});
```

DOCS HERE: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with res.render but it s using the template engine "pug" it was like this when I updated my http://localhost:3007/auth/login.

my route was:

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {res.render('auth/login)
```

now appeared like this with the new route.

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {res.render('auth/login.pug')});
```

always check out the route where our files are.