# How to return values inside .then function which is again inside a .then function and pass it in res.render?

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

So, I'm trying to pass values in my ejs file, but it's not working!

Except for the 'shortL' I'm getting [object promise] for 'first', 'second' and 'third' parameters, as for 'des' and 'gen' no values are returned.

I have tried every possible solution but nothing worked. Please help me!

This is my code:

```
app.get("/dashboard",(req,res,next)=>{
  db.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        
      var uid = user.uid;
      db.firestore().collection("Users").doc(uid).get()
      .then(function (doc){
          if(doc.exists){
              var shortL =doc.data().short_link
              var markId = doc.data().markid;
              
              //rosan's db
             let firstColl =secondarydb.firestore().collection("Affiliate_Marketing").doc(markId);
             let first =firstColl.collection('data').doc('install').get()
             .then(
                 function(doc){
                if(doc.exists){
                    var install =doc.data().number
                    return install;
                    }else{
                        console.log('No such document!');
                    }
                    
                })
            .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                })
                let secondColl= secondarydb.firestore().collection("Affiliate_Marketing").doc(markId);
               let second= secondColl.collection('data').doc('login').get()
                .then(
                    function (doc){
                    if(doc.exists){
                        var login =doc.data().number
                        return login;
                        }else{
                            console.log('No such document!');
                        }
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                let thirdColl= secondarydb.firestore().collection("Affiliate_Marketing").doc(markId);
                let third=thirdColl.collection('data').doc('purchases');
                third.get()
                    .then(function (doc){
                        if(doc.exists){
                            var puchases=doc.data().free_trial
                            return puchases;
                            }else{
                                console.log('No such document!');
                            }
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        })
               let pur= third.collection('users').doc("hz71u4cgZA6JQ9IR6Yeo").get()
                    .then(function(doc){
                    if(doc.exists){
                        var des = doc.data().skuDetails.description
                        
                         return des;
                          
                        }else{
                            console.log('No such document!');
                        }

                    })
                .catch(function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                    res.render("dash",{shortL:shortL,first:first,second:second,third:third,des:pur[0],gen:pur[1]});  
              }else{
                  console.log('No such document!');
              }
              
        })
      .catch(function(err){
              console.log(err);
        })
    } else {
      console.log("User signed out");
    }
    
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your head up, like, above the water. You shouldn't be nesting promises `then` and `catch` calls so deeply. Additionally, separate these chunks of code into logical functions, such as `getUser` and `getMarketing` -

```js
app.get("/dashboard",(req,res,next)=>{
  db.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
    if (!user) next(Error("Login required"))
    const { short_link, markid } = await getUser(user.uid)
    const { install, login, purchases, sku: [des, gen] } = await getMarketing(markid)
    res.render({short_link, install, login, purchases, des, gen })
  })
})
```

These independent functions like `getUser` are much easier to manage. Note, you don't need to attach `.catch` handlers directly to every promise as they will automatically bubble up once you sequence them properly -

```js
async function getUser(uid) {
  const doc = await db.firestore().collection("Users").doc(uid).get()
  if (doc.exists)
    return doc.data()
  else
    throw Error(`User not found`)
}
```

`getMarketing` is definitely more involved, but not necessarily more sophisticated. The biggest difference here is I put the four sub-queries into an array and used `Promise.all` to fetch all of them simultaneously. Simply check `exists` for each doc and return the `data` of your interest. Otherwise throw an error -

```js
async function getMarketing(markid) {
  // refs
  const ref = secondarydb.firestore().collection("Affiliate_Marketing").doc(markid)
  const installRef = ref.collection('data').doc('install')
  const loginRef = ref.collection('data').doc('login')
  const purchasesRef = ref.collection('data').doc('purchases')
  const skuRef = purchasesRef.collection('users').doc("hz71u4cgZA6JQ9IR6Yeo")
  // docs
  const docs = [
    installRef.get(),
    loginRef.get(),
    purchasesRef.get(),
    skuRef.get()
  ]
  // fetch
  const [installDoc, loginDoc, purchasesDoc, skuDoc] = await Promise.all(docs)
  // combine result
  if (installDoc.exists && loginDoc.exists && purchasesDoc.exists && skuDoc.exists)
    return {
      install: installDoc.data().number,
      login: loginDoc.data().number,
      purchases: purchasesDoc.data().free_trial,
      sku: skuDoc.data().skuDetails.description
    }
  else
    throw Error(`Marketing data not found`)
}
```

---

Another approach is to break `getMarketing` down even more -

```js
async function getMarketingInstall(markid) {
  const ref = secondarydb.firestore().collection("Affiliate_Marketing").doc(markid)
  const doc = await ref.collection('data').doc('install').get() // <-
  if (doc.exists)
    return doc.data()
  else
    throw Error("Not found")
}

async function getMarketingLogin(markid) {
  const ref = secondarydb.firestore().collection("Affiliate_Marketing").doc(markid)
  const doc = await ref.collection('data').doc('login').get() // <-
  if (doc.exists)
    return doc.data()
  else
    throw Error("Not found")
}

async function getMarketingPurchases(markid) {
  // STOP
}
```

See how you repeated yourself once already? And with the third function, you're about to do it again. Abstract the pattern with a function and use a parameter where specialization is required, `docid` -

```js
async function getMarketingData(markid, docid) {
  const ref = secondarydb.firestore().collection("Affiliate_Marketing").doc(markid)
  const doc = await ref.collection('data').doc(docid).get() // <- second parameter
  if (doc.exists)
    return doc.data()
  else
    throw Error("Not found")
}
```

Now with a reusable function, each doc takes care of its own fetch, `exists` check, `data` retrieval, and potential error. Combining them is now much easier -

```js
async function getMarketing(markid) {
  const docs = [
    getMarketingData(markid, "install"), // <- second argument
    getMarketingData(markid, "login"),   // <- second argument
    getMarketingData(markid, "purchases"), // <- second argument
    getMarketingSku(markid)
    ...
  ]
  return Promise.all(docs)
}
```

Getting the `sku` details is unique and so that would be it's own function

```js
async function getMarketingSku(markid) {
  // TODO: reader exercise. give it a shot!
}
```

---

You could write the same thing without `async` and `await`, but nowadays why would you? The nicest thing about using these control operators is they keep your variables in the same scope. By contrast, `then` isolates the results in separated scopes -

```js
app.get("/dashboard",(req,res,next)=>{
  db.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (!user) next(Error("Login required"))
    getUser(user.uid)
     .then(userData =>
       getMarketing(userData.markid)
        // combine
        .then(markData => {...userData, ...markData})
     )
     // resume outer chain
     .then(({ short_link, markid, install, login, purchases, sku: [des, gen] }) =>
         res.render({short_link, install, login, purchases, des, gen })
     )
  })
})
```

Or the alternative where you are forced to deepen with nested `then`. Neither of these programs are ideal -

```js
app.get("/dashboard",(req,res,next)=>{
  db.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (!user) next(Error("Login required"))
    getUser(user.uid)
     .then(({ short_link, markid }) =>
       getMarketing(markid)
         // down the rabbit hole we go ...
         .then(({ install, login, purchases, sku: [des, gen] }) =>
            res.render({short_link, install, login, purchases, des, gen })
         )
     )
  })         // <- look at this ragged edge of ) } }} ), gross
})
```

Comment: Couldn't have got a better explanation on this! Thankyou so much!

Answer (score -1):

The beautiful thing with `then()` functions is that they support Promises and Return/catches.

Ideally, you should be returning async methods direction in a `then()`, and when handling secondary requests, you can make the parent `then()` an async function and await results from within

```js
.then(async(snapshot)=>{
const res = await myAsyncMethod()
    .then(result => result.map(example=> example.sort()))
    .catch(err => throw err);
return res;
})
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(console.log);
```

It is also HIGHLY important to use arrow functions over anonymous functions, classic `function()` calls don't have binding, making calls in most frameworks independent, resulting in `this.state.etc` being null/undefined.

Comment: Where should I call res.render?

Comment: ideally when all the elements are ready to be pushed to the front of your app, most often at the bottom of the function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21843991/2301161

Comment: I'm actually new to all this, so what exactly is newPromiseEvent()?

Comment: @user16347260 the majority of code examples are low quality and offer little explanation and unfortunately beginners do not have the requisite skills to know the difference.

Comment: This code is incomplete and has many issues. 1) I assume the `then` is supposed to be `.then`, but what is the beginning of the expression? 2) `newPromiseEvent` is not a standard thing, nor is it defined here. 3) `.sort` is typically a function call on array types, but here it is not being used as a function. 4) `catch` and re-`throw` an error doesn't make any sense, nor can you `throw` in an expression, it would need to be in a block, `{ ... }`, 5) `.catch(console.log())` is also broken, as `.catch` expects a function. `.catch(console.log)` would work, but `.catch(console.error)` is better

Comment: 6) verbiage around "classic" `function()` calls is inaccurate. `function` declarations and expressions do have lexical scope, the only difference is arrow functions have a lexical _context_, which applies to the `this` variable. It's a strange point to make in this answer because your code doesn't use `this`, so your use of `function` is not a problem.